# Tooltip on disabled textbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

According to the TwitterBootstrap docs, and I quote:

> To add a tooltip to a disabled or .disabled element, put the element inside of a `<div>` and apply the tooltip to that `<div>` instead.

[Click here for the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Which I have done so:

```
    function AddToolTip(control) {
        d = jQuery(control).wrap("<div class='" + control.attr('name') + "' 
title='" + control.attr("data-title") + "' />");
        d.tooltip();
     }
```

And this function gets called like this:

```
$('#Area').attr('disabled', true).after(AddToolTip($('#Area')));
```

But the tooltip is not showing up, and it should show up when `hovered` or `clicked`.

I have a `textbox` which I enable/disable depending on another control. The same tooltip is shown whether the `textbox` is enabled or disabled.

What is it that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it like this:

```
$('#Test').attr('disabled', true).wrap(function () {
   return "<div class='" + $(this).attr('name') + "'></div>";
});
```

Here is the `AddToolTip()` function:

```
function AddToolTip(className) {
        d = $('.' + className);
        i = $('.' + className + ' :input');
        d.css({
            height: i.outerHeight(),
            width: i.outerWidth(),
            position: "top",
        })
        d.css(i.offset());
        d.attr("title", i.attr("data-title"));
        d.tooltip();
    }
```

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Return the element from the function:

```
    function AddToolTip(control) {
        d = jQuery(control).wrap("<div class='" + control.attr('name') + "' 
title='" + control.attr("data-title") + "' />");
        d.tooltip();
        return d;
     }
```

Without returning the element from the function there is nothing to append after `#Area` in this line:

```
$('#Area').attr('disabled', true).after(AddToolTip($('#Area')));
```

Which causes the `div` not to be added to the `DOM`

Comment: That was my original code, but that didn't work. Do I need to re-add the options or something?

Comment: @Quoter on second glance, try removing `return d` and `.after(AddToolTip($('#Area'))`.  You shouldn't need to append the element to the `DOM` `wrap` will do that for you.

Comment: Removing `.after(AddToolTip($('#Area'))`? But that function is the one responsible for adding the `wrap` in the first place. Do you mean something else?

Comment: @Quoter That is what I mean, or is `#Area` not already on the DOM?  Check out the documentation for wrap (http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) specifically the first example.  It says that wrap will insert the elements to the DOM, so there is no need for you to.

Comment: `#Area` is in the `DOM` yes, i'm just passing it as the control which is the `textbox`.

Comment: Then there is no need to append the wrapped div to the `DOM` using `after`, `wrap` will do this for you.  It might actually create an issue if two `DOM` elements have the same id.

Comment: One is `class` the other one is `id`, but no double id's. I removed the `after` and called `AddToolTip()` after disabling the `textbox`, but still nothing.